# Name for Logical Principle $(\varphi \to \psi) \to ((\neg \varphi \to \psi) \to \psi)$

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

The formula in the title seems like a pretty elementary logic principle.

In terms of an inference, it would be like a Constructive Dilemma:

$P \lor Q$

$P \to R$

$Q \to S$

$\therefore R \lor S$

where we set $Q$ to $\neg P$ and $S$ to $R$:

$P \lor \neg P$

$P \to R$

$Q \to R$

$\therefore R \lor R$  (which of course is just $R$)

and so if we assume of the law of Excluded Middle, we get:

$P \to R$

$\neg P \to R$

$\therefore R$

Does this inference have a name?

I note that if we rewrite the conditionals as disjunctions, it is related to $(P \lor R) \land (\neg P \lor R)$ which by Adjacency is equivalent to $R$ ... but I am thinking there must be some name used for the conditional form of this ... some special kind of 'Dilemma'.

Comment: "Gānto's Ax”.  («One day Tokusan told his student Ganto, "I have two monks who have been here for many years. Go and examine them." Ganto picked up an ax and went to the hut where the two monks were meditating. He raised the ax, saying, "If you say a word I will cut off your heads; and if you do not say a word, I will also cut off your heads."»)

Comment: I'd call this "proof by cases." It's the principle we use when we prove $\psi$ by saying "Case 1: $\phi$ holds. ...[prove $\psi$ in this case]. Case 2: Otherwise ...[prove $\psi$ in this other case]."

Comment: @AndreasBlass Thanks. Yes, I should have mentioned Proof by Cases as well, but like the Constructive Dilemma that one works with any kind of disjunction … I was hoping there would be a name for the special case where the disjunction is the P or not P. …

Comment: @MJD Love the name and story! I was actually already thinking something like ‘Fatalist Dilemma’:  whether you do something or not, you’ll always get the same end result.

Comment: I'm not sure if it has a name, but this one of the axioms in many Hilbert systems (see the fifth axiom of Hilbert's own [Hilbert system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Hilbert_systems), for example)

Comment: In Polish notation this would be CCprCCNprr.  A. N. Prior's appendix II p. 319 (or is it C. Prior, since AN == C?) of Formal Logic in a section on nicknames reads "Tarski or Dilemma, CCCpqrCCprr" with the note: "... Dilemma is so called because with q/0 it becomes CCNprCCprr".  Since CCprCCNprr and CCNprCCprr are the commutation of each other, it seems that Prior and some others would call the principle "Dilemma". But, it's two different formulas...

Comment: @Graviton Checking Prior's text it seems that it is used in Hilbert and Bernays influential Grudlagen der Mathematik of the 1930s... though that doesn't mean they had a nickname for it.

Answer (score 1):

The given proposition bears a kinship to the argument schema historically known as *consequentia mirabilis*, expressed in propositional form as

$$(\neg\psi\rightarrow\psi)\rightarrow\psi$$

A nice example (also, possibly the first on record) of *consequentia mirabilis* is  an argument set forth in a fragment from Aristotle (as translated by William Kneale in his article [Aristotle and the Consequentia Mirabilis](https://www.jstor.org/stable/628635)):

> If we ought to philosophise, then we ought to philosophise; and if we
> ought not to philosophise, then we ought to philosophise (i.e. in
> order to justify this view); in any case, therefore, we ought to
> philosophise.

We may notice that Descartes's hallmark statement, "I think, therefore I am", also exemplifies *consequentia mirabilis*. One cannot deny statement in a way that is not self-defeating. As Descartes's case suggests, *consequentia mirabilis* is intimately connected to our understanding of certainty and our rock-bottom presuppositions.

*Consequentia mirabilis* tells us that if a proposition $\psi$ is so strong that even its own negation concedes it, then it is true. From this perspective, we can construe the proposition $(\varphi\rightarrow\psi)\rightarrow ((\neg\varphi\rightarrow\psi)\rightarrow\psi)$ as a generalisation from self-referring to referring to any proposition $\varphi$ (including itself). We can explicate this view by comparing them in deductive form as

$$[\psi\rightarrow\psi],\;\neg\psi\rightarrow\psi\vdash\psi$$
and
$$\varphi\rightarrow\psi,\;\neg\varphi\rightarrow\psi\vdash\psi$$

Hence, if we wish to name it, the proposition in question might be called *generalised consequentia mirabilis*, for it can be said to be so at least in spirit, if not in letter.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!  I am still holding out for a name specific to this pattern ... but maybe there just isn't one! :P